# CORBA: Server as a Client

Tags: java, distributed-computing, corba, idl

I have been looking around and can't find an example of a CORBA server implemented as a Client as well.
I understand you can have a Client Connecting to a Server to Call methods but is there a way to call methods from the client service. I was thinking of having the interface for the client as a Server as well. Any suggestions where I can find examples or an example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this.  In fact, there is nothing special about doing this.  A CORBA ORB allows an application to fill both 'client' and 'server' roles simultaneously.

There is a simple example here: http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ds/programs/CORBA/Ciao.html

This implements a callback where the client pass an object to the server, and receives information when the server makes a call back to the client ... effectively reversing the roles in the interaction.